# Display jQuery-ui dialog box if <div> is not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a div block like this:

```
<div id="myDiv">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>Some data</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

All I want to do is check if the `<tr></tr>` has some text in it and display this div block in a dialog box, otherwise don't do anything.

What would be the best way to do this? I don't know how to check if the `<tr></tr>` is empty or not.

Comment: Your html is invalid; text can't be contained directly within a `tr` tag, it *has* to be within a `td` element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you have invalid html. The `tr` tag *can contains one or more th or td elements* (W3C). So fix your html.

As for validation using jQuery:

```
if ($('#myDiv table tr td').is(':empty')) {
}
else {
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JnyJs/1/

Comment: Sorry, my bad for the invalid HTML, just wrote the question in a rush. Will try the above solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can check the "emptiness" usng jQuery's [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function:

```
var $tr = $('#myDiv > table > tbody > tr');

if ($tr.text())
{
    // div is not empty
}
else
{
    // div is empty
}
```

You may want to [`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) the whitespace from the returned string.

Comment: The JS is fine. The problem is the markup, which has already been pointed out. http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/Dc3CC/

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Th25t/)

```
var text = $.trim($('#myDiv').text());
if (text) {
    alert(text);
}
```